# PHP get first paragraph of block

Tags: php, regex

I'm parsing plaintext emails and once I have the body text, I'd like to trim it down to the first paragraph.

Is this a regex situation (I guess searching from the start until `\n` or `\r`) or is this built into PHP more succinctly?

And example of the text might be:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum
>   dignissim, lacus ac ultricies convallis, arcu ante sodales magna, et
>   ultrices felis velit facilisis erat. Nam ullamcorper sagittis rhoncus.
>   Proin lacinia lorem in dolor condimentum, nec pretium orci interdum.
>   Morbi mattis, velit vel dictum efficitur, dolor nisi ullamcorper mi,
>   eu imperdiet risus metus ut ipsum. Pellentesque sagittis ultrices
>   velit, at maximus mauris venenatis in. Aenean et nisi efficitur,
>   tincidunt sapien sed, consequat quam. Cras ornare varius justo sed
>   pulvinar.
>
> Praesent magna odio, posuere a convallis et, viverra id augue.
>   Pellentesque auctor, nibh nec ornare porttitor, dolor dolor lobortis
>   justo, ut mollis tortor est eget diam. Morbi congue, massa sit amet
>   consequat convallis, purus magna tempus nibh, vitae vehicula dui neque
>   sollicitudin lorem. Etiam imperdiet maximus odio, in iaculis dolor
>   cursus ac. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
>   montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed feugiat efficitur odio vel
>   lobortis. Mauris pretium rhoncus velit, eu elementum nisl imperdiet
>   vitae. Morbi quis elit sed enim egestas aliquam. Suspendisse facilisis
>   ante id ipsum hendrerit, eget tincidunt arcu ullamcorper. Nullam
>   pellentesque efficitur nulla fermentum blandit. Mauris et felis
>   ornare, scelerisque velit eu, lobortis magna. Aliquam id egestas ante,
>   vitae ultrices dui. Integer tempus velit et ipsum sollicitudin
>   ultricies. Ut dignissim rutrum purus, at ultricies quam facilisis at.
>   Duis ultricies mauris ut urna pretium sollicitudin. Sed ut
>   sollicitudin sem.
>
> Curabitur sed mattis metus, id hendrerit purus. Ut sollicitudin tellus
>   at mi pellentesque iaculis. Nunc eu faucibus turpis. Duis leo elit,
>   ornare vel urna in, volutpat malesuada ante. Sed at diam nulla. Class
>   aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
>   inceptos himenaeos. Mauris a nunc eros. Mauris sed diam a purus
>   iaculis tincidunt ut quis sapien. In at turpis est. Donec mattis magna
>   mauris, id dapibus turpis hendrerit bibendum. Duis dapibus ante
>   lobortis odio efficitur porta. Morbi vitae risus mi. Integer volutpat
>   lacinia dui, non gravida massa egestas a.

And I'd want to save the first paragraph of that, however long it may be.

Comment: post the input text

Comment: It would be nice to know a little more about your input. Is it plain text? Maybe string.explode("\n") is what you look for, depending on your case.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I've updated my original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), as @maio290 said. You can do it like this :

```
$first = explode( "\n" , $yourString);
echo $first[0];
```

Here is a [working example](https://3v4l.org/aV62U).

Comment: Since you only need the first paragraph you should consider adding the 3rd paramter to limit the output array as `explode( "\n" , $yourString, 2)`. In case a new line char is found the first array element will be the first paragraph, while the second element with contain the rest of the text.

Comment: `explode("\n", ...` split a string by line, not by paragraph (paragraphs are separated by a sequence of two newlines).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit = PHP_INT_MAX ] )
```

> Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string
>   formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.

Comment: The problem with `explode` in this case is that the delimiter isn't know in advance: `\r\r` or `\r\n\r\n` or `\n\n` or other.

Answer (score 0):

*Is this a regex situation (I guess searching from the start until \n or \r) or is this built into PHP more succinctly?*

Yes and no.

If you are sure of the newline sequence, you can use `explode` ideally with the limit parameter set to 2 for your case.

One of the advantage of regex in this situation is the `\R` alias that stands for several newline sequences at the same time. This way you can use it without to know what kind of newline sequence is used in your string:

```
if ( preg_match('~(\S.*?\R)\R~s', $text, $m) )
    $text = $m[1];
```

But it isn't the only way to do it, It's also possible to read your string as a stream with `fgets` in conjunction with the option `auto_detect_line_endings` set to `true`

```
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);

$handle = fopen("data:text/plain,$text", 'r');

$result = '';

while ( false !== $line = fgets($handle, 1024) ) {
    if ( empty(trim($line)) )
        break;

    $result .= $line;
}
```